# Python: Very simple strptime() call throws error

Tags: python, macos, datetime, python-2.7

Some very simple code leads to a mystifying error, and Google gives me nothing...

Code:

```
import sys
import datetime

for line in sys.stdin:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
    print date
```

First few input lines on stdin:

```
20101119T141500
20101119T164500
20110310T081500
20110310T113000
20100218T113000
...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 5, in <module>
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 13, in <module>
    import time
  File "<path>", line 5, in <module>
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
AttributeError: _strptime
```

Platform: Mac OS X 10.7.3, Python 2.7.1

Comment: Is the line that triggers the error in your sample data?  I ask because I just ran that data through the same code in Python 2.7.3 with no errors.

Comment: aix: Yes, that's the complete output.
JohnGainesJr.: Just ran it with only the very first line of input. Quite interesting error, updating the post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You called your script "time.py", shadowing the `time` module. Don't do that.

Comment: I don't disagree with your assessment, but can it really explain the exception?

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Good catch. (+1)

Comment: This could quite possibly be your problem.  The time module has a strptime method, so it's quite possible there's shared code between datetime and time modules with the name _strptime, which you've hidden by naming your module time.py

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I would have searched a long time for that... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've had the same error happening to me *without* naming my module `time.py`.

Comment: @Ram: Doubt it. You had a different error, with the same exception.